# Octopus Deploy can't use Artifactory Docker registry

Tags: docker, nginx, artifactory, octopus-deploy

Trying to register a docker registry as a feed in octopus deploy. The docker repository is hosted in artifactory.

Octopus deploy returns error:

> feed endpoint foobar does not appear to expose a valid docker api

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to provide the exact api endpoint that docker is expecting instead of letting the reverse proxy on artifactory try and rewrite the url.

Instead of using this url

```
https://artifactory.example.com:5001/artifactory/foobar
```

Use this url

```
 https://artifactory.example.com:5001/artifactory/api/foobar/v2
```

Octopus can now use it as a docker registry